# Refresh the data of view after downloading a file in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Have searched for solutions and also tried different things but unable to find solution for this one. So my question is:
I have a form with fields like name,email,contact no for registration. Once i click on the button what i am doing is that i am allowing user to download a file for which i have written the code as below

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MBA_Programme(mba_programmeViewModel vm)
        {
            if (vm.mba_Id == null || vm.mba_Id == 0)
            {
                vm.Created_Date = DateTime.Now;
                vm.Created_By = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
                admin.addMbaDetail(vm);
                if (vm.Flag != null)
                {
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    return new FilePathResult(Server.MapPath("~/eiclandingpages/EIC-MBA.doc"), "application/msword");

                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("MBA_Programme", "EIC");
                }

            }

            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("MBA_Programme", "EIC");
            }


        }
```

The issue which i am facing is that once the form is getting downloaded the page is not getting refresh . I tried modelstate.clear() but not able to do it . I tried jquery also for location.reload but it refreshes but file wont downlaod and also refresh with delay.
Kindly help.
p.s: file i am getting from the folder in the project

Comment: If I understood correctly, what you want to accomplish is page refresh as you done downloading the file?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download may be helpful

Comment: @Pavel Durov Yes that's what i want to do but for some reason i am not able to do it